# apache log4j Adding an appender to root logger after calling getLogger() in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dynamic, log4j, rollingfileappender

I'm using Spring Boot and I have two separate Components.  One component supports database configuration properties for the application and initializes an Appender using properties pulled from the database.  Other components then just call getLogger() for a static logger as normal.

Currently, it appears that Spring is initializing the application configuration component first, so I've not been able to observe the behavior if it isn't initialized first.  My question is, should other beans be initialized first, will the appender tied to the root log apply to them during runtime, even though their logger was created before the appender was attached to the root?

So example code:

```java
@Component
class A {

    @PostConstruct
    private void configureSystem() {   
        EnhancedPatternLayout patternLayout = new EnhancedPatternLayout();
        patternLayout.setConversionPattern("%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t]: %m%n");
        DailyRollingFileAppender fileAppender = new DailyRollingFileAppender(patternLayout, "/logs/default.log", "'.'yyyy-MM-dd");
        fileAppender.setAppend(true);
        fileAppender.setName("DefaultAppender");
        fileAppender.setThreshold(Level.WARN);
        fileAppender.activeOptions();
        LogManager.getRootLogger().addAppender(fileAppender);
    }
}

@Component
class B {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(B.class);

    public void doSomething() {
        logger.info("I did something!");
    }
}
```

Class B won't "doSomething" until after everything has loaded, but I'm wondering if Class B gets instantiated first if that will affect anything.  Evidently there's no way to tell Spring which bean to instantiate first, so I can't assure that the configuration will go the way I need it to, but Spring instantiates this one first for now so I can't test it.  Will I run into problems?

Answer (score 0):

It seems Spring boot load Class A first, and then Class B. If Class B load first, then "log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger" will be thrown. I think you can initializate the logger in the @SpringBootApplication annotated class or use the log4j.properties file which will be loaded automatically.

Comment: It currently is loading them first, but I've read that I can't *guarantee* that it loads first.  Additionally, I can't use the log4j properties file or the @SpringBootApplication annotated classes because I need to load using this specific class for business requirements.